# change order of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

For function $f(x)$, let 
\begin{equation}
f(c)=\lim_{x \to c} f(x).
\end{equation}
Under what conditions the following holds?
\begin{equation}
f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} f'(x).
\end{equation}
For instance, let $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$,
\begin{equation}
f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.
\end{equation}
Is the following true?
\begin{equation}
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)'
\end{equation}

Comment: In your example, $f'(0)=0$. Is the limit of the derivative zero? In general though, derivatives may not be continuous.

Comment: You have your equality if the limit on the right hand side exist (assuming that $f$ is differentiable everywhere). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857139/derivative-of-continuous-function-exists-if-limit-of-derivative-exists).

Comment: It is true if $f$ is continuously differentiable at $x=c$. I'm not sure if that is an answer that is satisfactory for you though.

Comment: For any function $g$, for

$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=g(c)$ to hold, it suffices that $g$ be continuous at $c$.

So your question can be rephrased as "under what conditions is a derivative continuous?". A sufficient condition is the function twice differentiable, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx

Comment: @ArcticChar: But $f(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @JohnSmith Your $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$f(c)=\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$$

is true if and only if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$ and therefore

$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$$

is true if and only if also $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$.

For the example

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \implies f'(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$$

by $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$, are continuous at $x=0$ and both identities hold.

But the property is not true in general, e.g. $f(x)=|x|$.